# How to choose a post-procesing photography book

Tags: books

I am looking for some advanced book on post processing. I have the basic knowledge of the functionalities of Photoshop and camera raw. I had a look on Amazon, but it is not easy to know if a book is yet another Photoshop manual or if there is some real artistic content in it.

Where can I find such information?

Comment: The best post-processing book I ever got was one you might call "just another photoshop manual". It's not clear to me what kind of artistic book you envisage.

Comment: IMHO it is very good question. There is gazyllion books about technical stuff in Photoshop. But there are not very many which are incluting topics related to esthetic, composition, focus on shape or the colour and so on, especially it is very easy to get over-processed images in Photoshop, which at the end are kitsches.

Comment: You may struggle to find a one size fits all manual. Are you after genera; advice on how to use tools, such as the clone stamp, or maybe something more detailed such as how to clean skin?

Comment: I don't understand this question at all and it seems mostly like a book referral disguised as a question asking how to know the contents of a book. It also is really unclear if you want advanced post processing or artistic because the two are pretty different topics and you ask for both.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is probably to find reviews of the book and find out what someone else thought about it, and also if the Amazon listing has the "Look Inside!" feature, you could take a turn through at least the table of contents to get a sense of the book's contents.

Answer (score 2):

My answer will ignore the "photoshop" keyword from your question.

I had read some books about photography itself and not only about software.

Mostly artistic matters are covered in general books about photography and not about photoshop itself. Search books where there are the following keywords: "composition", "lighting", "rules of thirds", "black and white", "portrait" or "landscape".

I personally like books from Bryan Peterson (english), Scott Kelby (english), Tomasz Gałązka (polish), but there are many other good authors.